# Calculating "Market Index Dividend Yield" of the ASX

Tags: market, dividends, yield

In attempts to establish an investment portfolio with a long term horizon, the method of relative dividend yield has caught my attention.

I require the Market Index Dividend Yield to proceed. The formula in Spare and Tengler's "Relative Dividend Yield" is presented as

$$\mathrm{Market\ Index\ Dividend\ Yield}=\frac{\mathrm{Indicated\ Index\ Annual\ Dividend\ Rate}}{\mathrm{Current\ Index\ Value}}.$$

I am having trouble calculating the numerator of this formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially in context to the Australian Stock Exchange (ASX).

Thank you to all in advanced for you help.

Gustavo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to find a data set, containing the dividend yield information for all the companies listed in ASX20/50/100/200/300, the only way is for you to make it by researching the companies.

However I found [this dividend yield scan](http://www.marketindex.com.au/analysis/dividend-yield) to get you started.

Once you have the dividend yield rate for all the stocks in the given index, it is just a matter of taking the average of the list.